# What does $a = b$ mean when $a, b \in S$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If we have a set $S$ and $a, b \in S$. What does the expression $a = b$ mean in this context? Does it strictly mean that $a$ and $b$ refer to the same element of $S$. Or maybe they are different elements in $S$ but happen to be equal to each other?

Comment: They are the same.

Comment: Think of examples like $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ then x=y does strictly mean they are same element

Comment: The latter option makes little sense. If they are equal, they are not different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In first order logic and the model theory of first order logic, "a = b" means that $a$ and $b$ are the same object.

In the context of the language of set theory $\{\in\}$ and within axiom system of $\text{ZF}$, the axiom of extensionality asserts that if $a$ and $b$ have the exact same elements (i.e. $(\forall z)(z \in a \Leftrightarrow z \in b)$), then $a = b$.

Answer (score 0):

You need to distinguish between the letters $a$ and $b$ in the language we use to communicate and actual elements of the set. When we say: Let $a\in S$ we actually mean: let the symbol $a$ stand for an element of the set $S$. The $a$ is acting like a variable in a computer code. When you announce (in C):

int a;
int b;

a = 5;
b = 5;

Then $a==b$ is correct, even though the variables $a$ and $b$ are different. They are assigned the same value, so they stand for the same thing. One crucial difference though is that in C, being an imperative language, you can suddenly change the value of any parameter, so if $a==b$ was true two lines of code above, after:

a = 6;

it suddenly no longer holds. In a functional language (e.g., Scala) there is a difference between variables and values, so the analogy is better.

To make the distinction between the language level and the mathematical objects we talk about, consider the set $S$ of natural numbers. When we write $a\in S$ we certainly don't mean that anything like $a$ is in $S$, since it's not. What we mean is that $a$ refers to a natural number.